# How to Select count() inside select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

After hours of trying, i have finally come to terms i need assistance.

I'm trying to select a row from TableA and then count the number of cells of that row that are not empty.

I know this is faulty but it communicates my intention

```
SELECT COUNT(colName), 
    (SELECT (column1, column2, column3, column4) AS colName 
     FROM TableA 
     WHERE location= location) 
AS colCount
FROM TableA  
WHERE colName IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your code *does not* communicate your intention.  Sample data and desired results would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3a2f6/1)**

```
SELECT id, 
       (`column1` IS NOT NULL) + 
       (`column2` IS NOT NULL) + 
       (`column3` IS NOT NULL) as notnull
FROM Table1
```

Comment: Thanks Juan. This is simple and it worked. Thank s to all who also gave answers

Answer (score 1):

There may be a slicker way but a brute-force way would be:

```
SELECT
   location, 
    CASE WHEN column1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
    CASE WHEN column2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
    CASE WHEN column3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
    CASE WHEN column4 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
   AS colCount 
 FROM TableA
```

Comment: You dont need `CASE` on mysql `field1 IS NOT NULL` return 0 or 1

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I always like to be explicit since I am never sure if `true` is 1 or 0.

Comment: is easy 0 is false, everything else is true

Answer (score 0):

```
select location,
    sum(case when column1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
    sum(case when column2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
    sum(case when column3 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
    sum(case when column4 is not null then 1 else 0 end) cnt
from TableA
group by location
```

Comment: You dont need `CASE` on mysql `field1 IS NOT NULL` return 0 or 1

Comment: Thanks for the hint.